# libsecret equivalent for Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

Is there an equivalent for libsecret on Qt/KDE?
In GNOME/Gtk application I can link to the libsecret library and store the information securely, which can be retrieved later.

I found [this](https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain), but it is an external code and there is a license restriction.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but check if KDE also uses the same libsecret library.

Comment: what part of the license of qtkeychain you find overly restrictive? It was chosen to be as relaxed as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Qt has nothing really to do with keyrings. This is a feature/API of the desktop environment you are using.

libsecret is simply a GNOME based implementation for the SecretService D-BUS API (client side), so in theory, you could use `QDBus` too access it directy. A Qt-based implementation of the SecretService API does not exist - at least to my knowledge.

One more thing: Currently, only the GNOME-Keyring implements the "server-side" of SecretService. If you want to target KDE-Users as well, you will have to use the KWallet API instead. Have a look at [frankosterfeld/qtkeychain](https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain), as it creates a Qt-API around all those different keychain implementations, giving you idependent access to them

Other useful links:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html
- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/

Comment: I understand libsecret is GNOME/GTK-based implementation. And I presume QDBus is the same for KDE/QT. Am I right? Also I don't need the whole server side implementation - client side only to save and retrieve stuff. And finally - I presume there is a documentation somewhere on the main Qt documentation side?

Comment: QDBus is just a frontend to access the DBUS, not a frondend to the libsecret API which is provided over the DBUS. But yes, you can use it to access the SecretService API (which is what libsecret does) - it will just be a little more work. I added documentation links to the answer